# Secure https with nginx for Private IP address

Tags: nginx, https, server, openssl, devops

**Problem :** I want to run nginx with https, like `https://192.168.100.110`

**What I've tried :** I've followed the quick guide at https://www.humankode.com/ssl/create-a-selfsigned-certificate-for-nginx-in-5-minutes , I am able to open `https://localhost` properly on chrome but i want the self signed certificate to work with `https://192.168.100.110`

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: Have a look at this page :   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Yes, tried this too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update :** So the solution was pretty simple.
For IP addresses to work with the Subject Alternative Names we must provide the IP inside of the ext files that are used for creating certificate

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = localhost
IP.1 = 192.168.98.18
```

Now it's working properly

**Edit:** You can see the complete steps that I've followed from here: https://medium.com/@pavanskipo/how-to-secure-a-private-ip-address-with-https-nginx-ubuntu-ef8374dbfa4e.